# How do I export all hosts and services from Thruk?

Tags: nagios, thruk

We use Thruk within our business as a front end to different nagios backend servers.

I need to create a list of all the services and their hosts being monitored by these nagios servers but I cannot see an easy way to export a list.

I have been to configuration button in the bottom left corner and have managed to get lists I need loaded but I cannot cleanly copy and paste from this area and there is no export available.

I am wondering if there is another easy way to do this, going via the CLI seems like it would be a longer task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch a list of hosts and services from Thruks REST API.

There are some examples here: https://thruk.org/documentation/rest_examples.html

From the command line you can use the thruk cli tool to generate a list:

```
%> thruk r /csv/hosts?columns=name
```

this creates a simple text list of all hosts. Removing the /csv prefix will result in a json data structure.
Removing the columns=... will export all available columns.

Same can be fetched from the web rest api:

```
%> curl -H "X-Thruk-Auth-Key: ****" -g 'http://user:password@localhost/thruk/r/csv/hosts?columns=name'
```

API keys can be created in your user profile page.

The url `/r/hosts` retrieves all hosts as they are configured in nagios right now, Thruk config tool can be accessed by ex.: `/r/config/objects?:TYPE=host`.
A list of all available rest urls is here:
https://thruk.org/documentation/rest.html#_endpoints

Comment: thanks, looks like im on an older version with no api